# Action bar search reset using back button

Tags: android

I have action bar search menu. When I clicked on search icon, it is focused and soft keyboard shown. I want to reset search using onBackPressed event. when I firstly will press back button , soft keyboard will be hide . Again I will press back button, search view will be reset and collapsed.

I have tried in a such way but failed

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // It's expensive, if running turn it off.
       // DataHelper.cancelSearch();
        hideKeyboard();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
    private void hideKeyboard() {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) 
            getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mSearchView.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
```

my code hide keyboard but when i press again back button it navigates to previous intent.

Answer (score 0):

Stop calling the super method then you will not nevigate to previous activity only the soft key board will be hide.

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // It's expensive, if running turn it off.
       // DataHelper.cancelSearch();
        hideKeyboard();
        //super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Now you can do whatever you want.

Comment: But when I will press next button again , search view will be collapsed.

Comment: I need to navigate to previous activity but after collapsed search view .